# How to create a custom enterprise QGIS installer with plugins and symbols?

Tags: qgis, installation

I am looking at installing QGIS at a company level.  I would like my installer to install specific plugins, and add our company map symology.  Are there any ways to do this?  I have seen post about the custom GUI installer, but I didn't feel it was the same as my request.

Thanks...

Comment: is virtualization an option? we image window 7 with qgis (an all other software). with vsphere.

Comment: I can look at it.  As of now anything is an option.  Question back to you.  We have people who work remotely, would this option work with existing running computers?

Comment: As long as the remote users have a trusted (VPN is) connection then the re-imaging is automated overnight.

Comment: Thanks.  I will work with our IT department to give this a shot.